# How to create an object C#

Tags: c#, json, object

How to create an object in C# when you have following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    class Car
    {

        public class Id
        {
            public string brand { get; set; }
            public string model { get; set; }
            public string year { get; set; }
            public string r_no { get; set; }
            public string owner { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tires
        {
            public string front_value_mm { get; set; }
            public string back_value_mm { get; set; }
            public bool front_back { get; set; }
        }
}
}
```

I was trying to write something like that :
(That's my first time with c# )

```
I  Car car = new Car();
            Car.Id = car("Toyota", "Corolla", "1995", "AE2445", "James Cordel");
```

I know it has no rights to build. So I'm asking if I'm creating this code correctly at all? 
I need to create a new car object which will has all the information about the car and later on, I want to send those information about created cars into json file.

Comment: I would recommend you to read this first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming

Comment: You have declared `Id` and `Tires` classes as _nested classes_ of the `Car`. But you haven't declared that every `Car` must have an `Id` and a `Tires` _property_, and this means that every instance of the `Car` class won't have an Id and a Tires. Is this what you want? Check [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20628/A-Tutorial-on-Nested-Classes-in-C) for a tutorial on nested classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate your classes and use the nested classes as property types.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    class Car
    {
        public Id Id { get; set; }
        public Tires Tires { get; set; }
    }

    public class Id
    {
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string r_no { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tires
    {
        public string front_value_mm { get; set; }
        public string back_value_mm { get; set; }
        public bool front_back { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now you can new-up a car class with the nested values.

```
var car = new Car
{
    Id = new Id 
    {
        brand = "Honda",
        model = "Civic",
        year = 2017,
        r_no = "r_no",
        owner = "owner"
    },

    Tires = new Tires
    {
        front_value_mm = "front_value_mm",
        back_value_mm = "back_value_mm",
        front_back = true
    }
}
```

You should then be able to access the nested properties like this.

```
var brand = Car.Id.brand // Honda
```

If you want to assign values using parameters you need a constructor method.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
# You want to create object of Car.Id, so declare variable of that type
Car.Id carId;

# Then you create "new" Car.Id:
carId = new Car.Id {
    brand = "Toyota",
    model = "Corolla",
    year = "1995",
    r_no = "AE2445",
    owner = "James Cordel",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create an instance of your subclass

Hope this helps. Remember a public class is accessible every where in your code.

```
Car.Id id = new Car.Id();
  id = new Car.Id
  {
    brand = "Toyota",
    model = "Corolla",
    owner = "James Cordel",
    year = "1995",
    r_no = "AE2445"
  };
```